# Merge classes using Reclassify in python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, reclassify

When I run the Reclassify tool from arcmap 10.1 and assign a 1 to each of the crop types it combines them into one class. However, when I try to recreate this in python it does not merge the crop class types into one class. Below is the code:

[image: Reclassify code]

These are the parameters and results when I run it directly from the arc tool box and not from python. Below is what I am trying to reproduce using python:

[image: Reclassify tool]

[image: ToC after Reclassify tool]

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code into your question, rather than including it as a screenshot?

Comment: I was going to repost the code in non screen shot form, per Dan's request, but first I tried radouxju's suggestion and it worked. So I will post the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix is to save your look up table (save button on the "reclassify form") once, then you can reuse it several times using [ReclassByTable](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000sq000000.htm) instead of "Reclassify" in your script. "[Lookup](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000sn000000)" would probably be even better.

In order to minimize the potential sources of problem, I would also suggest that you avoid special characters such as spaces in the names of your classes. "_" can be used in place of " ".

Answer (score 0):

The solution as suggested by radouxju was to eliminate spaces from the `CLASS_NAME` values in the attribute table. For what ever reason, it was not reading them correctly in the `remapValue` statement even though they were quoted.

Once the attribute table was edited to have string values without spaces I changed the `remapValue` statement to reflect the new spaceless values. Below is the code change that fixed the problem:

**Code changed from:**

```
myRemap = RemapValue([["Soybeans",1],["WinWht Soybeans",1],["Soybeans Cotton",1],["Soybeans Oats",1],["Corn Soybeans",1],["Barley Soybeans",1]])
```

**To:**

```
myRemap = RemapValue([["Soybeans",1],["WinWhtSoybeans",1],["SoybeansCotton",1],["SoybeansOats",1],["CornSoybeans",1],["BarleySoybeans",1]])
```

Thanks to radouxju for the thoughtful suggestion.

Comment: This answer is effectively the same as radouxju's. Rather than posting the same answer again, you should upvote radouxju's answer and accept it.